# sqlalchemy + MSSQL ошибка при получении суммы (func.count)

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

Добрый день. Написал программу, загружаю данные в СУБД и потом ими пользуюсь. Когда использовал sqllite, все работало, попробовал настроить на MSSQL получаю ошибку при получении данных.

вот вся программа

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
from models import *
engine = create_engine("mssql://@test")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
```

а вот и проблемный кусок кода

```
querry = session.query(func.sum(StockOnDate.ValueOut)).scalar()
querry[0]
```

получаю ошибку

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000',
>   '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]��� ������
>   �������� varchar(max) ���������� ��� ��������� sum. (8117)
>   (SQLExecDirectW)') [SQL: 'SELECT sum([StockOnDate].[ValueOut]) AS
>   sum_1 \nFROM [StockOnDate]']

ошибка в func.sum
подскажите, как ее обойти?

Answer (score 0):

ответ нашел: похоже для SQLLite не важен тип данных. У меня был выбран тип String и все работало, а для других СУБД это важно, пошел исправлять